# Docker images with maven and docker binaries

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile

I need to create a docker image that allows me to build and run tests on a maven project and also allows me to run docker commands, which I need for the tests.

The maven:latest works for one part and docker:latest for another but I have not been able to find an image that allows me to run both, so I'm guessing that in my Dockerfile I'd have to set FROM maven:latest and FROM docker:latest but I don't know how they are used to obtain one image with both.

It's my first time using Docker, so please have some patience.

Comment: A shell script on your host might be a better answer.  There's no way to merge two Docker images, and running Docker commands from within a container is a little bit tricky.  If I really needed to do this, I'd start from a Java-based image and then install the Docker CLI using whichever tools that image had available (`apt-get install` if it's Debian-based, for example).

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze This was the good direction and I was able to install docker and maven from a debian image and run docker commands!

Answer (score -1):

[Multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) might solve your problem.

> With multi-stage builds, you use multiple FROM statements in your Dockerfile. Each FROM instruction can use a different base, and each of them begins a new stage of the build. You can selectively copy artifacts from one stage to another, leaving behind everything you don’t want in the final image.